# Cannot enable Bitlocker encryption on system drive

Tags: windows-7, bitlocker

There are source configurations:

- I use Windows 7 SP1 Ultimate x64.
- My system has two partions C: (system) and D:
- My PC is in organization's domain

I don't have TPM microchip on motherboard so I want to use flash drive to store password. I edited Group Policy to enable that feature but had no success. I still get message 'A compatible trusted platform module must be present on this computer...' I googled hardly but found nothing about my problem. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Can I use BitLocker on an operating system drive without a TPM version 1.2?

Yes you can, but there are some restrictions:

- The BIOS must have the ability to read from a USB flash
  drive in the boot environment.
- You must enable the
  "Require additional authentication" at setup Group Policy setting, which
  is located in Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows
  Components\BitLocker Drive Encryption\Operating System Drives.
- You
  must select the "Allow BitLocker without a compatible TPM" check box.

---

> Yes, you can enable BitLocker on an operating system drive without a
>   TPM version 1.2, if the BIOS has the ability to read from a USB flash
>   drive in the boot environment. This is because BitLocker will not
>   unlock the protected drive until BitLocker's own volume master key is
>   first released by either the computer's TPM or by a USB flash drive
>   containing the BitLocker startup key for that computer. However,
>   computers without TPMs will not be able to use the system integrity
>   verification that BitLocker can also provide.
>
> To help determine whether a computer can read from a USB device during
>   the boot process, use the BitLocker system check as part of the
>   BitLocker setup process. This system check performs tests to confirm
>   that the computer can properly read from the USB devices at the
>   appropriate time and that the computer meets other BitLocker
>   requirements.
>
> To enable BitLocker on a computer without a TPM, you must enable the
>   Require additional authentication at setup Group Policy setting, which
>   is located in Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows
>   Components\BitLocker Drive Encryption\Operating System Drives. You
>   must select the Allow BitLocker without a compatible TPM check box.
>   After this setting is applied to the local computer, the non-TPM
>   settings appear in the BitLocker setup wizard.

Source [Can I use BitLocker on an operating system drive without a TPM version 1.2?](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee449438%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#BKMK_HSRequirements)